# Como acessar índice de um array javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Ao dar `console.log` na variável `overlays`, tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
[Oh, 36: Oh, 37: Oh, 97: Oh, 98: Oh, 99: Oh, 100: Oh, 101: Oh]
0: Oh
36: Oh
37: Oh
97: Oh
98: Oh
99: Oh
100: Oh
101: Oh
length: 102
__proto__: Array[0]
```

Devo acessar esse array através do valor de suas chaves (36,37,97,98,99,100,101) e que podem ser diferentes.

Ao tentar acessá-las com o método abaixo, o valor das chaves vem apenas como (0,1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
$.each(overlays, function(a, b) {
    console.log(overlays[a]);
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

você pode pecorrer as chaves usando um for convencional.
Segue um exemplo:

```
var array = { 0: 'Oh', 36: 'Oh', 37: 'Oh', 97: 'Oh', 98: 'Oh', 99: 'Oh', 100: 'Oh', 101: 'Oh' }

for (var key in array) {
    console.log({
        key: key,
        value: array[key]
    });    
}
```

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/g82aac1d/

Answer (score 5):

Se um array (e não somente um objeto) possui propriedades numéricas não sequenciais, o "tamanho" desse array (i.e. sua propriedade `length`) é um a mais que seu maior índice não-negativo. Se seu array não tiver elementos com índice não-negativo, seu `length` é zero.

O método [`jQuery.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/), quando aplicado a arrays, percorre todos os "elementos desse array", em ordem sequencial. Isso significa que qualquer elemento "faltando" virá como `undefined`. Outras propriedades, incluindo índices negativos, não serão retornados por esse método.

A solução portanto depende do seu objetivo: se seu array é na verdade um objeto, com propriedades arbtitrárias, e você quer pegar todas, você pode usar um `for..in` como sugerido na [resposta do TobyMosque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50311/215) ou o `Object.keys` como sugerido na [resposta do Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/50313/215). Tomando o cuidado de ignorar o `length`, é claro, se isso for do seu interesse.

Mas se você quer tratar seu array como um array mesmo, sem índices negativos, e consultar só o índice ignorando as entradas em branco, eu sugiro usar o `$.each` mesmo testando o valor por `undefined` (ou `null` e `undefined`, ou qualquer valor *falsy*, dependendo do seu objetivo):

```js
var overlays = ['Oh'];
overlays[36] = 'Oh';
overlays[37] = 'Oh';
overlays[97] = 'Oh';
overlays[98] = 'Oh';
overlays[99] = 'Oh';
overlays[100] = 'Oh';
overlays[101] = 'Oh';

$.each(overlays, function(a, b) {
    if ( b !== undefined ) {
        document.querySelector("#saida").innerHTML += "<p>" +
            "Índice: " + a + "; Elemento: " + b +
        "</p>";
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="saida"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Essa array que colocás-te `[Oh, 36: Oh, 37: Oh, 97: Oh, 98: Oh, 99: Oh, 100: Oh, 101: Oh]`não é uma array... parece mais um objeto. De qualquer maneira para teres chaves e valores então é `Object` que precisas.

Para extraires todas as chaves do objeto numa array podes fazer:

```
var chaves = Object.keys(meuObjeto);
```

Se quiseres iterar todos as propriedades desse objecto podes usar um `for var in` mas o mais rápido é usando Object.keys:

```
var chaves = Object.keys(meuObjeto);
for (var i = 0; i < chaves.length; i++){
    var propriedade = meuObjeto[chaves[i]];
}
```

Se sabes a chave/propriedade cujo valor queres mudar podes usar duas formas:

```
meuObjeto['chave']
// ou
meuObjeto.chave
```

Comment: Pode ser uma *sparse array*, ver resposta do mgibsonbr

Answer (score 1):

Você poderia usar o método `indexOf` que serve para localizar através do valor atribuído ao índice, como no exemplo a baixo:

```
var produtosRestaurante = array()

 produtosRestaurante[0] = 'Cachorro Quente' 
 produtosRestaurante[1] = 'X-Burger'
 produtosRestaurante[2] = 'Suco Natural'
 produtosRestaurante[3] = 'Refrigerante'
```

`produtosRestaurante.indexOf(X-Burger)` O que seria recuperado ao utilizar esse
método seria o índece cuja se atribuiu o valor(X-Burger nesse caso), ou seja o indice recuperado é o de número 1

Answer (score 0):

O método `jQuery.inArray(<chave>, <array>);` retorna o índice do elemento se for encontrado no array passado, caso ele não encontre ele retornará -1;